# Nginx : deactivate cache for html single page app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, nginx

I have set up a single page app for my app using AngularJS and gulp. Each time I run `gulp build` it will compile my assets in minified JavaScript and CSS such as `app98D9898.css`. For each build the number will change randomly.

I have an HTML page called `index.html` which will try to load the CSS and JavaScript files.

Until now everything is working as expected.

I use NGINX as a proxy to serve my static files. The big issue I have: it seems Chrome and Firefox are caching the `index.html` file. Thus, If I build new version of my app, the browsers will continue to load the old version.

I'm looking for a solution to rpevent this behavior using NGINX to specify to not cache the `index.html` file. Do you have an idea how I could proceed?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a location in the server block to give html files a short expires time and disable the proxy cache.

```
location ~* \.(html)$ {
   expires              1h;
   proxy_cache          off;
   ...
}
```